# JSON format in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2008

My simple question do we have json support in SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT cucode 
FROM dbo.Customers 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

is returning error

Thanks and regards,

Imran

Comment: Simple answer is: no.

Answer (score 1):

FOR JSON AUTO  isn't supported until sql server 2016.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server

Comment: so If I want to write a web service to get data from sql server It can return only xml format.

Comment: If it's easy enough to convert xml to json in C# using XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

Answer (score 1):

JSON support has been only available since SQL Server 2016 - see the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) - it states what version it applies to.

Comment: thanks for all replies.